# How many times i need to declare UIApplication SharedApplication in my class in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

In my iOS app , i need to access some data from `AppDelegate`.
So i used like that

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
    self.app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.app.arrayFromApp addObjects:self.myArray];
    [self.app loadSomething];
}
```

I want to know Is this enough when i declared above code One time in `ViewDidLoad` and i can access from everywhere (Methods,variable,etc...) in this class?.

Or

Do i need to declare that code every method when i have to access data from `AppDelegate`?.

example.

```
- (void)methodOne
{
 self.app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 self.app.isTrue = self.isTrueOrNot;
}

- (void)methodTwo
{
 self.app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [self.app loadSomething];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is enough one time in your class to declare if you are using `app` as class level `ivar`

```
 self.app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

You don't need to declare it within every method if you are declaring `app` as a property in your class

Comment: Yes. i used iVar.So i need to declare just one time and i can use everywhere from this class? thz :)

Comment: This assumes your app property is strong (or retained). If it is weak you will lose the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define this in your appdelegate.h file

```
#define APPLICATION ((AppDelegate*)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate))
```

Just a shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making app a readonly property and instantiate it lazily.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (readonly, nonatomic) AppDelegate *app;

@end


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize app = _app;

- (AppDelegate *)app
{
    if (_app == nil) {
        _app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }
    return _app;
}
@end
```